# Código alfa numerico MYSQL

Tags: mysql

quero um código INTERNAMENTE no MySQL um código randômico, com 2 letras,1 numero, 1 letra, 2 numeros

> AB-1A-21 - DA-2B-35 - CI-3U-23

como proceder ?

Comment: `varchar`.. pelo seu exemplo, `varchar(8)`

Comment: Amigo, @rLinhares, eu editei a pergunta, o que eu quero na verdade é saber se posso gerar esse código direto no mysql sem ajuda do php.

Answer (score 1):

O default do AUTO INCREMENT em MySQL é sempre int!
Para o seu caso específico, você precisará criar uma function com os critérios que você menciona acima. A coluna para armazenar o resultado é a varchar(8).

Comment: Carlos, obrigado pela resposta, editei minha pergunta filtrando melhor o conteudo. Eu quero é gerar aquele exemplo numa coluna do mysql de forma randomica. COMO SE FOSSE AUTO-INCREMENT.

Comment: Você cria uma function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html
**CREATE FUNCTION f_increment () RETURNS varchar(8)
-- cria a lógica do hash fazendo select na tabela para ver o max id e incrementa 1
---return hash**



Daí é só utilizar da seguinte forma
**insert into tabela (id,txt,dt) values (f_increment (),'texto',CURDATE())**

Comment: carlos, obrigado pelo seu interesse em ajudar. vou veficicar como fica seu código.

Comment: Outra dica é fazer com hexadecimal, onde você pode fazer operações de adição. Veja link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html

Bem trabalhoso essa atividade!

Comment: meu interesse consiste em gerar um numero de facil decoração. por isso dois 2 letras, 1numero+1letra+2numeros. o exadecimal até serve. mais não supre minha expectativa em razao da limitação de letras. isso será impresso em um adesivo e colocado a dispor de outras pessoas. Em breve le apresentarei o sistema, contendo sem duvida uma parte de sua contribuição.

Comment: minha tabela está completa. quero apenas acrecentar essa coluna. e quero que ela tenha os valores no modelo que eu indiquei. são 6 digitos ao invés de 8. não armazenarei os traços.